# How to configure proguard properly in android?

Tags: android, proguard

I am already enabling proguard by help of this link http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html but not reduce apksize and also get code from apk in reverse engineering process,so how to configure.
Thanks in advance

Comment: revere-engineering of an obfuscated-code will will surely return you the code but in a meaning-less way  :)

Comment: apk size also not redused Waqas